# How to make a submodule behave as. a submodule in git?

Tags: git, android-studio, module, git-submodules

I have created 2 submodules in my project. But, these submodules seem to have the commit history of the entire project, not just for the submodule. When I push from the submodule to remote repository for submodule, the entire project's commits, and not just
the submodule's commit gets pushed.

In other words, my submodules aren't behaving as submodules. How do I fix it?

Comment: How have you created these submodules?

Comment: @phd Created with File > New > New Module

Comment: 1. Android Studio? You should mention it in the question and add the tag [tag:android-studio]. 2. I don't know AS but I'm not sure the command "New Module" creates a new git submodule.